# CakePHP Put Reset & Submit Button on the Same Line

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I find that when I'm using $this->Form->submit the submit button is wrapped inside div.form-group.

```
echo $this->Form->submit('submit', array(
            'div' => 'form-group',
            'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
));
echo $this->Form->button('Reset', array('type'=>'reset' ,'class' => 'btn btn-primary'));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `div` to `false` to disable the wrapping div on both buttons, then just echo the div manually:

```
echo '<div>';
echo $this->Form->submit('submit', array(
    'div' => false,
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
));
echo $this->Form->button('Reset', array(
    'type'=>'reset',
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
    'div' => false
));
echo '</div>';
```